# Setting tcp connectivity in embedded Linux

Tags: tcp, embedded-linux

With ARM, Debian 10, as a root, I try to set up static ip, TCP to outer world through Windows (adapter sharing):

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 192.169.200.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
ip route flush table main
route add default gw 192.169.200.200  eth0
echo "nameserver 192.169.200.200" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

It takes me several trials to execute adding-gateway before I can ping outer world by names. Times in the middle `route add default gw 192.169.200.200  eth0` returns `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`. Finally, after repeating it again with pings, ping finally works. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not have flushed main table which might have wiped the link local entry from the routing table. So instead of following command:

"ip route flush table main"

you could use following:

"route del default"

I hope it helps you understand.